# The Graph Generator listener is generating only one graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, test-report, performance-testing

I tried generating graphs of my tests using Graph Generator listener, but only one graph of Response Times over Time is generated in the output folder. How can I generate more graph??? Any suggestions???

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove all the listeners from your Test Plan apart from the [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true
   ```

This way JMeter will not rely on previous listeners results and will work with the .jtl results file directly.

More information:

- [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Results file configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)